# MUI TextField sx props does not apply styles

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm trying to style a TextField component in a one-off fashion using the `sx` prop:

```
<TextField
    size="small"
    sx={{
        padding: '1px 3px',
        fontSize: '0.875rem',
        lineHeight: '1.25rem',
    }}
    {...params}
/>
```

I'm using MUI v5. If I inspect the input element, the styles are not applied. What am I missing?

UPDATE: it seems the styles are actually added to the wrapper element via its generated class. But I need to style the input element.

I've also tried using `inputProps`, but that did nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can style the constituent components by targeting their classes directly through `sx`. For example:

```
      <TextField
        label="My Label"
        defaultValue="My Value"
        size="small"
        sx={{
          ".MuiInputBase-input": {
            padding: '1px 3px',
            fontSize: '0.875rem',
            lineHeight: '1.25rem',
          }
        }}
      />
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/customizedinputs-material-demo-forked-jog26e?file=/demo.js

Comment: Docs, if you need them: https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-nested-component-styles

Answer (score 3):

What you can use is the `inputProps` prop. This lets you pass the `sx` prop as a regular object down to the input component. For example:

```
<TextField 
  size="small"
  inputProps={{
    sx: {
      padding: '1px 3px',
      fontSize: '0.875rem',
      lineHeight: '1.25rem'
    }
  }}
/>
```

Docs here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props