# MUI TextField not accepting sx properties

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to simply figure out why when I try to apply sx props to my MUI textfield it's saying the following:  `Property 'sx' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OutlinedTextFieldProps'.`

I've looked at the following StackOverflow questions and I'm not doing anything drastically different than their answers.
[StackOverflow Question about MUI TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491779/mui-textfield-sx-props-does-not-apply-styles#:%7E:text=What%20you%20can%20use%20is%20the%20inputProps%20prop.,lineHeight%3A%20%271.25rem%27%20%7D%20%7D%7D%20%2F%3E%20Docs%20here%3A%20https%3A%2F%2Fmui.com%2Fmaterial-ui%2Fapi%2Ftext-field%2F%23props)
Their documentation even states that it can use the sx: [MUI TextField Docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/)

My textfield:

```js
<TextField
   fullWidth={true}
   label='Lift Name'
   variant='outlined'
   sx={{
     '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
         color: 'green',
         backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
   }}
/>
```

Comment: Can you indicate MUI version that you are using? I'd expect to see this error if you were to use MUI v4.

Comment: Where do you import the `TextField` from? probably the issue is related to it **if you're using MUI v5**

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments! I have the following in my package.json: `"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
        "@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
        "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.11",` I thought the same thing, but it does indeed look like I have the latest version of material UI.

Comment: I import the text field at the top with the following: `import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';`

Comment: `@material-ui/core` is actually v4 :) You should migrate to v5 to use the `sx` prop.

Comment: Ahhh shoot, I knew it would be something real simple. Just to double check, is '@mui/material' the v5 version? Also, thank you a ton for this!

Comment: Yes, `@mui/material` is the correct import path for v5. You can also remove all `@material-ui` packages from your dependencies once you complete the migration.